# like query in sqlite android not working properly

Tags: android, sqlite

The following is my function:

```
public Cursor get_names(String n){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    //" select * from Record where name like  '"
    String query = " select * from Record where name like  '"+n+"' ORDER BY name";

    Cursor res =  db.rawQuery(query,null);
    return res;
}
```

To this function i send, n like:

```
String name = element.getText().toString(); 
if(name.length()!=0){
                name = name+"%";
            }
            else
            {
                name="%";
            }
            Cursor display = dbms.get_names(name);
```

This is working fine if the name matches in the database, But the query is not working if the name does not match..

How do if find the name received by the edittext is matching in the database or not..

EDITED:  I am using display later like this:

```
Vector<String> array = new Vector<>(100);
 display.moveToFirst();
                do {
                    array.add(display.getString(1));
                } while (display.moveToNext());
```

Comment: What do you mean with "not working"?

Comment: if you got `res.getCount() > 0` then result found in `Database`

Comment: @CL. My app crashes...for example if in database i have names like one,two if i pass n value as 'f%' the app crashes ...unfortunately my android studio is having some update issues and my device is not getting connected with studio and even emulator does not run [ so i can not post the error and log here.. ].

Comment: @MD thanks solved it by checking the getCount() before using my display cursor..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem..thanks to M D

i changed the way of using my dsplay cursor into this

```
 if(display.getCount()>0) {
                display.moveToFirst();
                do {
                    array.add(display.getString(1));
                } while (display.moveToNext());
            }
            else{
                //name not found case..
            }
```